# fullpage.js - navigational elements to control slides and stay fixed in same position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

**CONTEXT**

I want to have a series of images which control slides (i.e. `moveTo('section1', 1)`, etc.). However, I don't want to have to put them on every single slide - instead I would like them to always stay in the same position on the screen, with only the slide in the background changing. Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: If you could throw up a simple codepen or jsfiddle that would be rad

Comment: probably doing them position fixed will help :) need code though

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a fixed position to those element. Use CSS for it: `position:fixed`.

And example is provided in the fullpage.js files, in the fixedHeaders.html` file, which [is also available online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/fixedHeaders.html#firstPage).

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to tell what you mean without an example, but try to reason about this:

You'll have a parent element holding all of your slides. Either in this element, after all the slides **OR** outside of this parent & right after it, you will have your "controls" element.

```
<slides>
  <slide></slide>
  <slide></slide>
  <slide></slide>
  <!-- ..etc.. -->
</slides>
<controls>
  <control goToSlide(1) />
  <control goToSlide(2) />
  <control goToSlide(3) />
</controls>
```

...and then what you can do is `position: absolute` the `controls` and (maybe) use `z-index` to position them above the slides.